# How to subtract apex variable in IF condition of Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, if

```
<td style="text-align:center">
{!IF(Project.pse__Planned_Hours__c - {!grandtotalAH})> 0,Project.pse__Planned_Hours__c-Project.Total_Billable_Hours__c,0)}
</td>
```

I want to subtract {!grandtotalAH} inside the IF condition. can somebody suggest any workaround or right way achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're in a "merge field", you don't need to keep merging:

```
{!IF(Project.pse__Planned_Hours__c - grandtotalAH > 0, 
Project.pse__Planned_Hours__c - Project.Total_Billable_Hours__c, 0)}
```

Comment: gah, beat me by mere seconds

Comment: @DerekF You'll have a lot of time today, I'm going to be busy all day at work.